# Нейронная сеть для синтеза звуков ( к примеру собачий лай)

Tags: нейронные-сети

Есть задача синтеза звуков, например собачий лай.

Подскажите как можно решить эту задачу, на основе какой сети, спасибо!

Comment: Нейронная сеть это система для угадывание образов. На входе что-то, на выходе наиболее похожий образ. Каким боком тут генерация звуков? Что на вход подавать собираетесь? Фото Мухтара?

Comment: @pepsicoca1, НС используются не только для угадывания образов. Это только одна из областей применения НС.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: нейронные сети можно использовать и для генерации данных по паттерну. Одна из распространённых методик такова: *разворачиваем* нейронную сеть и подаём ей на вход сгенерированный белый шум до тех пор, пока на выходе (бывшем входе) мы не получим искомый объект. То есть мы вместо вычисления свойств объекта вычисляем сам объект по его свойствам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать [рекуррентные LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) или [Generative adversarial network (GAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) сети.

Пример LSTM: ["How to Generate Music using a LSTM Neural Network in Keras"](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-generate-music-using-a-lstm-neural-network-in-keras-68786834d4c5)

Пример GAN: [MuseGAN](https://salu133445.github.io/musegan/model)

Comment: Спасибо! А GAN для этого не подходит?

Comment: @AleksanderK., GAN тоже подходит)